# Sun (NPR900R) Server Cabinet Input Power Range

Tags: ups, rackmount

The ISP I work for purchased a Sun NPR900R Server Cabinet.  For usual operation, a UPS will provide the power supply.  Is it possible to operate this at 120 V input range?

Answer (score 0):

Google isn't helping me find out anything about a Sun NPR900R Server Cabinet.  What is it?  Can you provide a link to the documentation for it?